# singly linked list in the C++ standard library or other widely-used libraries?

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Seems that there is only doubly linked list (but no singly linked list) in the C++ standard library, right? Is there any widely-used C++ libraries with singly linked list?

Comment: Is there any reason to care what the underlying implementation is as long as it _acts_ like a linked list?  Just curious...

Comment: @D.Shawley: I only need singly linked list in most cases, so I do not want the overhead imposed by doubly linked list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [slist](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Slist.html), which is an SGI extension (`__gnu_cxx::slist`)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <ext/slist>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  __gnu_cxx::slist<int> sl;
  sl.push_front(1);
  sl.push_front(2);
  sl.push_front(0);
  std::copy(sl.begin(), sl.end(),  // The output is 0 2 1
            std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
  std::cout << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I prefer this answer because I prefer not to importing another library, though Greg Hewgill's answer is also correct. Thx guys!

Answer (score 8):

There is the [`slist`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/intrusive/slist.html) class from Boost that is a singly linked list implementation.

Comment: It appears that there is an `slist` in some vendor implementations of the STL, but not in the C++ Standard Library.

Answer (score 8):

Just for reference...

Time has passed and C++11 has brought us the [std::forward_list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list) container that is implemented as a singly-linked list and essentially does not have any overhead compared to its implementation in C.

Compared to `std::list` this container provides more space efficient storage when bidirectional iteration is not needed.

Warning: missing `push_back` method ([std::forward_list and std::forward_list::push_back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742462/stdforward-list-and-stdforward-listpush-back))