# std::forward_list and std::forward_list::push_back

Tags: c++, c++11, std, forward-list

I'd like to use [std::forward_list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list)

Because:

> Forward list is a container which supports fast insertion and removal
>   of elements from anywhere from the container

But there's no *std::forward_list::push_back* implementation.

Is there a high-performance way to add support for the one or no reason to do it?

Comment: Why do you need it? Do you want to grow your list both ways?
Can't you use `push_front()` just as easily?

Comment: Note that the bidirectional `std::list` also supports "fast insertion and removal of elements from anywhere from the container", and has `push_back`. The cost is an extra pointer per entry. Is memory so tight that you can't use that?

Comment: I want to keep sorting the list

Comment: @Mike Seymour, I believed that the singly-linked list is much faster))

Comment: @AlexanderGuiness: If you want it sorted, maybe `set` or `multiset` might be a better choice? That maintains a sorted order, at the cost of slower insertion and removal (although inserting a single element will be quicker than inserting it into a list then resorting).

Comment: @AlexanderGuiness: The singly-linked list will be marginally faster for the operations it supports (since each operation has to update half as many pointers), but both have the same complexity orders. It will most likely be slower if you want to support a fast `push_back`.

Comment: @Mike Seymour, Thanks, I figured, and I'll use a simple `std::list`

Comment: @Alexander - *"I want to keep sorting the list..."* - If you continually sort the list, then I believe you turn the list into a ***O(n^2)*** algorithm. You get ***O(1)*** or ***O(n)*** insertion, ***O(n log n)***  sort, and you do it ***n*** times. ***O(n log n)*** * ***O(n)*** is bounded by ***O(n^2)***. (And if I recall my algorithm analysis class correctly).

Comment: @Alexander - *"I want to keep sorting the list..."* - If you continually sort the list, then I believe you turn the list into a ***O(n^2)*** algorithm. You get ***O(1)*** or ***O(n)*** insertion, ***O(n log n)***  sort, and you do it ***n*** times. ***O(n log n)*** * ***O(n)*** is bounded by ***O(n^2)*** (or is it ***O(n^2 log n)***). (And if I recall my algorithm analysis class correctly).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`std::forward_list` supports fast insertion and removal, *but not traversal to the end*. To implement `.push_back`, you'll first need to get to the end of the list, which is O(N) and not fast at all, which is probably why it's not implemented.

You could find the iterator to the last element by incrementing `.before_begin` N times

```
auto before_end = slist.before_begin();
for (auto& _ : slist)
  ++ before_end;
```

and then use `.insert_after` or `.emplace_after` to insert the element:

```
slist.insert_after(before_end, 1234);
```

Comment: Of course, a `forward_list` could be amended by storing an extra iterator pointing to its end. That way, `push_back` could be done in O(1) time.

Comment: So there's no any reason to implementation `push_back`?

Comment: @KennyTM It would still lack bidirectionality.

Comment: @KennyTM: no, `std::list` is doubly-linked. What I mean is store an extra pointer to the end in the head structure, exactly what Mike Seymour suggests.

Comment: Or perhaps write `auto before_end = std::next(slist.before_begin(), std::distance(slist.begin(), slist.end()));`

Comment: @larsmans Why not just use the `queue` class instead of `forward_list`?

Comment: std::forward_list is not *just* a singly-linked list. It is intended to also occupy the absolute minimum possible memory (in particular an empty list should be only one word). It doesn't even keep its own size, so it's certainly not going to waste space on tracking the tail of the list.

Comment: @LoganKling, the stupid thing is that std::queue can use std::list but not std::forward_list, even though a queue only needs nodes with a single pointer each.

Answer (score 30):

I recommend against `std::forward_list` just like I recommend against `std::list` in almost all situations. Personally, I've never found a situation in my code where a linked list was the best data structure.

In C++, your default go-to data collection should be `std::vector`. It gives you efficient `push_back`, if that is what you really need. It technically does not give you efficient deletion and insertion from the middle if you only look at abstract big-O complexity measurements of that one operation. In the real world, however, `std::vector` still wins **even for inserting and deleting in the middle**.

As an example, Bjarne Stroustrup created a test of a 100,000 element `std::list` vs. `std::vector`. He would search each for an element and delete it. Then he would find an insertion point and insert into the middle. He could have use a binary search on the `std::vector`, but did not to make the comparison 'more fair'.

The results show a strong win for `std::vector`, even in this situation where `std::list` is supposed to be strong. Simply traversing the `std::list` takes so much longer because of how far apart in memory all of the objects are. `std::list` is not cache-friendly, which is possibly the most important thing for modern processors.

[The complete talk by Bjarne Stroustrup](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Keynote-Bjarne-Stroustrup-Cpp11-Style)

[Thorough explanation of the effects, with benchmarks at multiple sizes](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/340797/Number-crunching-Why-you-should-never-ever-EVER-us)

Note that this second link here gives some situations of where you may possibly want to use a `std::list`, such as when the size of the elements is large. However, I've been in a situation where I have many elements in a particular order and needed to delete some.

These elements were larger than any built-in type, but not huge, perhaps 20-30 bytes each on a 32-bit computer). The number of elements was large enough so that my entire data structure was a few hundred MiB. The data collection was a set of values that could theoretically be a valid based on currently known information. The algorithm iterated over all elements and removed elements that could no longer be valid based on new information, with each pass probably deleting somewhere around 80% of the remaining elements.

My first implementation was a straightforward `std::vector` approach where I deleted invalid elements as I traversed. This worked for small test data sets, but when I tried to do the real thing, it was too slow to be useful. I switched to a `std::list` as the container, but used the same algorithm, and I saw significant performance improvements. However, it was still too slow to be useful. The winning change was to switch back to a `std::vector`, but instead of deleting elements in place that were bad, I created a new `std::vector`, and any elements I found that were good were put into that `std::vector`, and then at the end of the function I would simply discard the old `std::vector` and use the new one, and this gave me about as much of a speed up over the `std::list` as the `std::list` gave me over my original `std::vector` implementation, and this was just fast enough to be useful.

Comment: Or.. maintain a "dead" flag on each element that you update instead of deleting elements, only compact the vector when the number of dead elements reaches a certain limit. Will not work with primitive types in the vector of course, but very interesting answer, ta.

Comment: Nice rant, but I don't see how this answers the question at all. There are many situations where a singly linked list will do fine; in fact I think any implementation behind the scenes uses essentially a singly linked list of frames to represent the runtime stack within a single thread (the frames may be consecutive in memory, but are not equal-sized so cannot be addressed directly as in a vector). Typically if you just need a simple stack or queue structure, you can implement that easily using a list (and an additional pointer to its end in case of a queue).

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen It solves the problem rather than answering the question. The problem is that they want a high performance data structure for insertion and removal. `std::forward_list` is rarely the data structure to achieve goals this broad. As for your specific example, `std::forward_list` doesn't help there, either (unless I am misunderstanding, which I may well be). If the frames are not equal sized, that implies dynamic allocation. A linked list of pointers is almost never a better data structure than a vector of pointers.

Comment: The very best use I've found for a single-linked list is for atomic add/removal of items. The pointers can be updated using cmpxchg. Although I don't believe the std::forward_list does so, sadly.

Comment: Yes, multi-threaded code is the one place where a good linked list data structure can be useful, but `std::forward_list` is not that data structure.

Comment: That technique of traversing the container, copying into a new container 
 only what is to be retained, is how the modern Java garbage collectors work.

Answer (score 7):

The point of std::forward_list is to be an ultra-stripped-down version of std::list, so it doesn't store an iterator to the last element.  If you need one, you'll have to maintain it yourself, like so:

```
forward_list<int> a;

auto it = a.before_begin();

for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    it = a.insert_after(it, i);
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no `push_back` because the list doesn't keep track of the back of the list, only the front.

You could write a wrapper around the list that maintains an iterator to the last element, and implements `push_back` using either `insert_after` or `push_front` depending on whether the list is empty. This will get rather complicated if you want to support the more complex operations (e.g. `sort` and `splice_after`).

Alternatively, if you don't need `push_back` to be fast, it's straightforward to do it in linear time.

Unless memory is extremely tight, the best solution is to use `list`. This has the same performance characteristics as `forward_list`, and is bidirectional, supporting `push_back` as well as `push_front`; the cost is an extra pointer per element.

Comment: +1, just my idea. `sort` wouldn't be so hard, btw.; just sort the underlying `forward_list` and find the new end. Since sorting is O(*n* lg *n*), it dominates the end-finding.

Comment: @larsmans: That's true. It might be trickier to `splice` in constant time though (if you're splicing a normal `forward_list` that doesn't track its end).

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to have both constant-time `size` and constant-time `splice`, which is why there was variation in the complexity of the operations on a `std::list`. "One or the other, but not both". That's also why there was a bit of grumbling about `std::list` getting constant-time guarantees for `size` in C++11.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunatelly I can't add a comment (low reputation) but I just wanted to mention that one of the forward_list & list advantages is that insert-delete operations do not invalidate iterators. I had an application where collection of elements was growing while iterating and processing individual elements. Absence of iterator invalidation allowed me to implement segment scan (begin of the list as start of the segment and begin of the last segment as end).