# Move the first element to the end of the forward_list

Tags: c++, c++11

I know that std::forward_list is a single linked list. I'm wondering how to move the first element(head) to the end of the forward_list. No copies or creating new nodes!

I've tried the following:

```
std::forward_list<int> l2 = {10,11,12};
auto beginIt = l2.begin();
beginIt = std::next(beginIt);
l2.splice_after(l2.end(),l2,l2.begin(),beginIt); 

for(int n : l2)
    std::cout << n << ' ';
std::cout << '\n';
```

But it doesn't work. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [std::forward\_list and std::forward\_list::push\_back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742462/stdforward-list-and-stdforward-listpush-back)

Comment: @KenY-N, here is no push_back function.

Comment: But it's the same requirement, finding the last element in the list as `l2.end()` is one after the end.

Comment: @KenY-N: In this case used the same forward_list, without creation a node.

Comment: The linked question is a piece of the answer to this one, because to do the move correctly you need an iterator to the last element. But a proper answer to this one should explain why, and what to do with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your purposes, `splice_after` needs an iterator to the last element. That is, the element right before `end()`. There's no cheap way to get this:

```
auto pos = l2.begin();
while(std::next(pos) != l2.end()) ++pos;
```

Then, `splice_after` for a single element asks for an iterator pointing *before* that element. For the first element, that is `before_begin()`:

```
l2.splice_after(pos, l2, l2.before_begin());
```

Comment: If we use `auto before_end=l2.begin();` before `splice_after` we get iterator on the last element. So it can be used next time without while-loop. This behaviour I wanted to get. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [rotate](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/rotate/):

```
std::rotate(l.begin(), std::next(l.begin()), l.end());
```